# Converting .jpg to .mp4 with ffmpeg with lots of files in a broken order

Tags: video, ffmpeg, jpeg, mp4

so I tried to enhance a 16m long video with real-ESRGAN and ffmpeg, but since I have no idea how to actually get the files to sync in order, I am here.
So I have been given a file on how it's supposed to operate, and I understand most of it, except for one thing I just can't figure out, and that's the file order it's supposed to compile it in.

*ffmpeg -i out_frames/**frame%08d.jpg** -i test.mp4 -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -r 23.98 -pix_fmt yuv420p test.mp4*

This is the file, and the bolded part is very confusing for me since the original file that was given with it actually has about 100 or more files(frames), and the "08" here makes no sense to me.

Basically what I need is "that bolded part" but so it can compile an order like this:

frame00054953.jpg  <-- End frame

frame00001946.jpg  <-- Start frame

I've deleted the intros to save filesize because it's currently sitting at 53,010 files with 140GB.

I just tried different combos to see if one could work out(like frame%01946d, dumb stuff like that), but could only get the basic one file to render and that resulted in a single frame, over 16m long audio...
Going on their website, I also completely lost my mind.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved this with just a simple *-start_number* command I found later.